# spring webflux - websocketclient threads not terminating

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-webflux

I'm using a Spring WebFlux `WebSocketClient` to subscribe to and handle messages from a remote web socket.  During processing the Flux of messages from the remote socket will sometimes unexpectedly complete (or terminate on error) causing the web socket client's `onComplete` (or `onError`) callback to execute. When this occurs, my `onComplete` and `onError` callbacks publish an event.  An event listener responds by calling the function that creates another web socket client which connects to the same external web socket and the socket processing starts over again.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to free the `WebSocketClient` resources after a client completes processing.  This causes unused threads to accumulate in the JVM. In particular the threads on which the first `WebSocketClient` were running (`WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1`, `WebSocketClient-SecureIO-2` and `parallel-1`) remain in a waiting state and new threads are started for the new 'WebSocketClient'. I thought calling `close()` on `WebSocketSession` would solve the problem, but it does not.

The pattern of my implementation is:

```
public void startProcessing() {
   WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
   Mono<String> subscribeMsg = Mono.just("...");

   client
      .execute(uri, webSocketSession ->
          webSocketSession
             .send(subscribeMsg.map(webSocketSession::textMessage))
             .thenMany(webSocketSession.receive())
             .map(webSocketMessage -> ...)
             .buffer(Duration.ofSeconds(bufferDuration))
             .doOnNext(handler)
             .doOnComplete(() -> webSocketSession.close())
             .then())
       .subscribe(
            aVoid -> LOGGER.info("subscription started"),
            throwable -> {... publish restart event ...},
            () -> {... publish restart event ...});
}

public void restartEventListener() {
    startProcessing();
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can prevent unused `WebSocketClient` threads from accumulating in the JVM?

Comment: Could you explain which threads are those? To which resource are they attached? Are you creating one websocket client or multiple ones? How are they accumulating? In this example you're using the client just once.

Comment: Brian ... thanks for your interest.  I've added edits to answer your questions.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I'm also trying to find a solution to it.

Comment: I did not find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

A `WebSocketClient` is pooling resources, so you should reuse the same client for many requests.

You should avoid doing processing inside `doOn*` operators. Those are side-effects operators and are executed synchronously on the current `Scheduler`. Fore more efficiency, you should use other operators. You could map the websocket message to a `Flux<DataBuffer>` and then use `DataBufferUtils::write` to write those to a file and still leverage the same reactive pipeline instead of using the side-effects operators.

Closing the websocket session in one of those is not a bad idea, although I'd use `doOnTerminate` which is triggered for both success and error scenarios.

Also I don't understand the goal of publishing events to restart the processing phase. Using the `retry` and `repeat` operators and the same client should work just fine and be more efficient.

Comment: I can't get `retry` and `repeat` to work in this case because the processing flow is composed of a Mono (returned by `send`) followed by a Flux (returned by `thenMany`).  Since `send` is supposed to complete prior to `thenMany` I can't put a repeat between the two, and if I add `repeat` in the method chain after `thenMany` it fails to retrigger the `send`. Hence I publish an event as a way to get back to the start of the processing chain. I'll try reusing the `WebSocketClient`.

Comment: RE: `handler` in `doOnNext` ... it writes data to disc.  Since the socket data stream is continuous and unbounded, I can't wait for the Flux to complete and return data for me to write to disc. So my implementation writes data periodically: `buffer` waits X seconds, then pumps data into `doOnNext` for the handler to persist the data, and the process repeats.  Based on your comment, this might cause problems if the handler takes more than X seconds, so I'll think that over.  But conceptually I think I have to use `doOnNext` in this case.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: If I map the websocket message to a `Flux<DataBuffer>`, where would I run `DataBufferUtils::write`? I can't run it in the consumer function of `subscribe()` because it is never triggered. This is a key point: after the buffer's duration is exceeded and processing continues, the consumer function in `subscribe()` is not triggered, and the processing chain between `thenMany()` and `then()` just repeats indefinitely.  So I need to use an operator within the pipeline to execute the write to file.  What operator can I use other than `doOnNext`?